# Sqldependency error

Tags: vb.net, sqldependency

I want to create a system notification between SQL server Express and Visual studio 2012 (Vb.NET), i looked for this example [Microsoft] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
I followed all the instructions, but the result wasn't right, the event handler of the changing doesn't happen !!!!
and i noted that in sql server management studio: in the  [databasename] -->service broker--> queues--> System Queues --> dbo.EventNotificationErrorsQueue   and dbo.QueryNotificationErrorsQueue.
i don't know how to fix this problem, and why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved, so i want to share the answer to everyone :

the authentication of the database was the problem so I changed the authentication to 'sa' then the handling work perfectly, using :
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::databasename TO sa;

Comment: I have spent all day implementing many tutorials and copying codes no one told me this. It has changed me from :( to :).